# C++ Limit The Number of Characters Entered

Tags: c++, char, limit

For my program, I have a function that gets the users input. I made the code so far, but how how can I make it where when I'm typing and if I go over the text limit, it will delete the previous character and not allow me to type anymore unless I backspace the characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    char word[10];
    cin >> setw(5) >> word;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Your name is: " << word << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The short answer is that (with standard, portable code) you can't. You can control how much text you read, but you have no control over what the user enters. If you really need to control how much they can type, you might want to look into things like `curses` on Linux or console functions on Windows.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I remember someone was able to do this before by using a chars. It is possible.

Comment: For me, writing most editor type functions has always turned out to be pointless.  So, maybe you are allowed to use command line parameters to provide user input (but without the prompts)?  That particular style of editing gives the user up-arrow recall, tabs, and several other very nice functions.  And any overly long inputs can be easily detected, and rejected with an explanation and exit the program. The user then simply up-arrows and edits the previous command in the shell.  Trying to duplicate what is trivially available has not been worth the effort.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN, I actually just made a working one myself. I might make another post and see if their is any way to compact the code.

Comment: @ThatCoderBryan - It is ok to add your own answer (and I think accept it!) to a question you wrote.  Show your work ... and reward yourself.  (There may be restrictions based on rep)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a library such as the [GNU Readline Library](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). This library takes care of all the details involved in reading lines of text from the user, with line editing and features such as maximum length.